# Angular factory not returning value to controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that calls service to execute a call to a socket.io server. The service works (sends commands to socket.io) but the callback (promise) on the controller is not fired. What am I missing?

```
.controller('SettingsCtrl1', function($scope,socket) {
    socket.switchSpace(spaces).$promise.then(function(data) {
      alert("CALLBACK: " + data); //does not fire
    });
});
```

and in my service:

```
.factory('socket', function (socketFactory) {

  var connection = io.connect('http://example.com:3000');

  var socket = socketFactory({
    ioSocket: connection
  });

  socket.switchSpace = function(spaces) {
    socket.emit('leaveSpace', spaces.oldspace, function(callback) {
      if(callback == 'success') { //we make it here
        socket.emit('joinSpace', spaces.newspace, function(callback) {
          if(callback == 'success') {
            //we make it here
            return callback;  //does not make it back to controller
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }

  return socket;
});
```

Comment: Your controller didn't call the function that returns `callback`...so it is getting returned to the `socket.emit` closure, not your controller.

Comment: @ShaunScovil   I can't get anything back to the controller, even if I hard code  'return success' into the end of the socket.switchSpace function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service method socket.switchSpace() does not return a promise (or, as you have implemented it in your controller, an object with a $promise property).

So in order to make this work, you need to:

- inject the $q service in your socket factory
- create a deferred promise using $q.defer()
- resolve the promise in your callback
- return the promise
- call .then(function onSuccess() {...}) in your controller, not .$promise.then()

Putting it all together, your service should look like this:

```
.factory('socket', function (socketFactory, $q) {

  var connection = io.connect('http://example.com:3000');

  var socket = socketFactory({
    ioSocket: connection
  });

  socket.switchSpace = function(spaces) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    socket.emit('leaveSpace', spaces.oldspace, function(callback) {
      if(callback == 'success') {
        socket.emit('joinSpace', spaces.newspace, function(callback) {
          if(callback == 'success') {
            deferred.resolve(callback);
          }
        })
      }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return socket;
});
```

And your controller should look like this:

```
.controller('SettingsCtrl1', function($scope,socket) {
    socket.switchSpace(spaces).then(function(data) {
      alert("CALLBACK: " + data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @ShaunScovil ... this runs perfectly. Obviously I need to study up on $q and promises.